# Why do I need global:: here?

Tags: .net, namespaces, ninject

I have run into ...I don't think I would call it a problem as much as I would a quirk. It confuses and confounds me.

I am adding `Ninject` to my site. It works fine. No questions about troubleshooting Ninject specifically, but I encountered this when setting up my modules...

Here is my `SessionModule.cs` file.

```
namespace Lightcast.Web.Mvc.Injection.Modules {
    public class SessionModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule {

        public override void Load() {
        }
    }
}
```

Also shown in this screenshot.

[image: SessionModule.cs]

I get the error

> Unknown type 'Modules' of Lightcast.Web.Mvc.Injection.Ninject

Now if I change it to this ...

[image: SessionModule.cs(2)]

It works just fine. So obviously there is a namespace collision. What I do not understand is **why**?  I have *never* encountered this before. It just seems like the absolute oddest thing to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason seems to be that somewhere in your project a namespace or type named `Lightcast.Web.Mvc.Injection.Ninject` exists that hides the global `NInject` namespace.

Comment: I get it. I have a static class named `Ninject` in the same namespace, and it can't determine whether I am calling the static class or the original root namespace. That makes sense, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 4):

There is a class or namespace named `Ninject` somewhere inside namespace `Lightcast.Web.Mvc.Injection.Modules` or one of its parent namespaces.

The error occurs because the C# compiler looks up types and namespaces by trying to find them inside the current namespace and working its way towards the global namespace if it cannot.